# Using OpenACC in a fortran77 project ,but has no effect and not output kernel information

Tags: fortran, openacc, pgi, fortran-common-block

I  have a fortran77 reservoir simulation project ,and want to use openacc directive to accelerate implementation,the compiler is PGI visual fortran ,a subroutine as follow:

SUBROUTINE jbild(a, b, impl,
     [              ia, ja, neqa, kvst, ka, ibkmax, nja, ndima, nbmxc,
     [              isymm)

```
USE parameter_data
USE connect_data
USE contrl
  IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)

  include 'eleme.com'
  COMMON/G9/NEXG(MNOGN)

  COMMON/shiftf/SFTMIN(mxcom)
  COMMON/gm_nm/gamman(njamax)
  common/jocab2/uf(3,ibnd+maxlay),flw(3),fsav(3,ibnd+maxlay)
 [     ,fsum(3),fsums(3), fdsum(3), fdp(3), fdiag(3)

  COMMON/well_1/iwell(mnel)
  COMMON/well_2/pwell(mnogn),vol_w(mnogn)

  COMMON/source/qm_bc(mxcom)

  integer ndima, nbmxc, ibkmax, nja, impl(ibkmax),
 [      ia(ibkmax+1), ja(nja), neqa(ibkmax), kvst(ibkmax+1),
 [      ka( nja+1), isymm(nja)
  double precision a(ndima), b(nbmxc)

  double precision fdsav(mxcom),eps
  parameter (eps=1.0d-300)

  COMMON/scndv2/densn(maxnn,mxphs+1),accn(maxnn,mxcom),acck(mxcom),acck_All

double precision Epsilon1(mxphs), Epsilon2(mxphs)

IDiagonal_dominace = 1 !--- =1:    JACOBI                           


  do 1 i=1, ka( nja+1 ) ! ndima 
     a(i)  =  0.0d0
1 continue

  do 3 i = 1, kvst( ibkmax + 1) ! nbmxc 
      b(i) = 0.0d0
3 continue

EpsilonMax1 = 0.0
EpsilonMax2 = 0.0
NEpsilonMax1 = 1
NEpsilonMax2 = 1


  do 1000 i=1, ibkmax
    inode=i
    imat=matx(i)

    do iphas=1, nph
      fsum(iphas) = 0.0d0
      fsums(iphas) = 0.0d0
      fdsum( iphas ) = 0.0d0
      fdsav(iphas) = 0.0d0

      do index=1,  ia(i+1)-1 - ( ia(i) )
        fsav(iphas, index) = 0.0d0
      enddo

    enddo

    if(iwell(inode).eq.0) then
       do iphas=1,mnph
         qm_bc(iphas)=0.0d0
       enddo
    elseif(iwell(inode).eq.1) then
      call bc_ev(INODE)
    elseif(iwell(inode).eq.2) then
      call bc_well(inode,ishift,ia, ja,nja)
    endif
    call eqnsa(INODE,IMAT,ishift)

    jconet=0
    do 12 index = ia(i)+1, ia(i+1)-1
        id = ja( index )
        jconet=jconet+1
        if(dabs(gamman(index)).le.eps) goto 12
        call eqnsf(INODE,id,imat,ishift,index,jconet,impl(i))
        do 14  iphas = 1, mxphs

         if( impl(i) .eq. 0                    )then
           a( ka(isymm(index)) + iphas ) = fdp( iphas )
         else
           fsav(iphas, jconet) = flw(iphas)
         endif
  14          continue
         if( (impl(i) .eq. 0) .AND. (IDiagonal_dominace .eq. 1) )then !---            
            a( ka(isymm(index)) + 1 ) = fdp( 3 )
            a( ka(isymm(index)) + 3 ) = fdp( 1 )
        endif
  12      continue


    do 15 iphas = 1, mxphs
      b( kvst(i) + iphas ) = -fsum( iphas )
    if(EPSN1.GT.0.0.AND.EPSN2.GT.0.0) then  !--                       -----------------
        Epsilon1(iphas) = abs(b( kvst(i) + iphas )/(acck_All+1.0D-20)) !---                   
        Epsilon2(iphas) = abs(b( kvst(i) + iphas ))                    !---                   
        if(EpsilonMax1(iphas).LT.Epsilon1(iphas)) then
            EpsilonMax1(iphas) = Epsilon1(iphas)
            NEpsilonMax1(iphas) = i
        endif
        if(EpsilonMax2(iphas).LT.Epsilon2(iphas)) then
            EpsilonMax2(iphas) = Epsilon2(iphas)
            NEpsilonMax2(iphas) = i
        endif
    endif                                                   !--------------------------

    if( impl(i) .eq. 0) then
          fdsav( iphas ) = fdiag( iphas)
      else
          fsums(iphas) = fsum(iphas)
          fdsav(iphas) = fdiag(iphas)
      endif
  15      continue

    if(IDiagonal_dominace.EQ.1)then  !---            
        b( kvst(i) + 1 ) = -fsum( 3 )   
        b( kvst(i) + 3 ) = -fsum( 1 )
    endif


    do 2000 icol=1, nph

      isave=1

      ishift=1
      call save_v(INODE,ISAVE,ICOL)
      call shif(INODE,ICOL,stemp)

      if( impl(i) .eq. 0)then
         kupdat = 0
      else
         kupdat = 1
      endif

    if(MOP(10).NE.0) kupdat=0 !--- add by Diyuan, 2014-6-6                    
   call eosms(inode,kupdat,b,kvst)  

    if(iwell(inode).eq.0) then
        !$acc loop
       do iphas=1,mnph
         qm_bc(iphas)=0.0d0
       enddo

    elseif(iwell(inode).eq.1) then
      call bc_ev(INODE)
    elseif(iwell(inode).eq.2) then
      call bc_well(inode,ishift,ia, ja,nja)
    endif
    call eqnsa(inode,IMAT,ishift)

   if( impl(i) .eq. 0                  ) go to 100
   if( impl(i) .eq. 0 .and. icol .gt. 1) go to 100

      jconet=0

      do 150 index =ia(i)+1, ia(i+1)-1
          id = ja( index )
          jconet=jconet+1
          if(dabs(gamman(index)).le.eps) goto 150
        call save_tauf_C(idcon(index),1,ICOL)
        call EOSMS_Connection(idcon(index),kupdat)      !-- add by Diyuan, 2012-6-22
          call eqnsf(INODE,id,imat,ishift,index,jconet,impl(i))
        call save_tauf_C(idcon(index),2,ICOL)

           do 101 irow=1,mxphs
             if( impl(i) .eq. 1)then
               a(ka(isymm(index))+(irow-1)*mxphs+icol) = +(flw(irow)-fsav(irow,jconet))/stemp
             else
               a(ka(isymm(index))+irow) = (flw(irow)-fsav(irow,jconet))/stemp
             endif

  101           continue
        if(IDiagonal_dominace.EQ.1)then  !---            
            a_temp = a(ka(isymm(index))+(1-1)*mxphs+icol)
            a(ka(isymm(index))+(1-1)*mxphs+icol) = a(ka(isymm(index))+(3-1)*mxphs+icol)
            a(ka(isymm(index))+(3-1)*mxphs+icol) = a_temp
        endif
  150       continue

  100       continue


      do 120 irow=1,  mxphs
         itemp =  ka( ia(i) ) + (irow-1)* mxphs

         if( impl(i) .eq. 0 ) then
            a(itemp + icol) = ( fdiag(irow) - fdsav(irow) ) / stemp
            if( icol .eq. 1)then
                a( itemp + icol ) = a( itemp + icol ) + fdsum(irow)
            endif
         else
            a(itemp+icol)  = + (fsum(irow) - fsums(irow ))/ stemp
         endif



  120       continue

    if(IDiagonal_dominace.EQ.1)then  !---            
        itemp1 =  ka( ia(i) ) + (1-1)* mxphs
        itemp3 =  ka( ia(i) ) + (3-1)* mxphs
        a_temp = a(itemp1 + icol) 
        a(itemp1 + icol) = a(itemp3 + icol)
        a(itemp3 + icol) = a_temp
    endif

      isave=2

      call save_v(INODE,ISAVE,ICOL)

  2000    continue
  1000  continue




  ishift=0

  RETURN
  END
```

But when I add the openacc directive ,I can’t see the  output information and data replication information ,in console there isn’t also outputing  kernel execution time information. I have set up the environment variables and command-line parameters to ensure that the information output. :

```
    !$acc parallel loop
    do iphas=1, nph
      fsum(iphas) = 0.0d0
      fsums(iphas) = 0.0d0
      fdsum( iphas ) = 0.0d0
      fdsav(iphas) = 0.0d0

      do index=1,  ia(i+1)-1 - ( ia(i) )
        fsav(iphas, index) = 0.0d0
      enddo

    enddo
   !$acc end parallel
```

The array store in .com file . I  don’t  know why  the openacc has no effort ,and what impact  the goto-statement have , would I like to delete goto-statement the program to modify the program for using openacc

Comment: Hi WeiH-CUG,

What type of PGI license do you have?  OpenACC is only available with the "Accelerator" license.
- Mat

Comment: Your code is NOT FORTRAN 77, there is no USE in FORTRAN 77.